# Concrete5 - Change location of images

Tags: image, concrete5

Currently images are located in `/files/` in the root directory. Is it possible to host the images elsewhere?

For example, they are currently hosted on `http://www.domain1.com/files/` and I want them to be located at `http://www.domain2.com/files/`.

And how does the `/files/` structure work? What do all the numbers mean?

For example, Wordpress stores their files in `/uploads/`, then the structure has the year in the uploads folder: `/uploads/2016/[images placed here]`

And Concrete5 has `/files/4557/` and then another random folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have a look at 'storage locations'
../dashboard/system/files/storage

And: http://documentation.concrete5.org/developers/working-with-files-and-the-file-manager/file-storage-locations